# Grey screen showing up on layout xml after switching to Androidx

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, androidx

After switching to Androidx, when I go back to my activity xml, it shows nothing but a grey screen with "androidx.constraintlayout....ConstraintLayout"

I tried messing around with the gradle and switching the constrained layout version but no luck.

Someone please help me with this because I dont know what to do.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hammad.firstapplication"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'


}
```

Comment: share your xml  code .

Comment: Just close Android Studio and open it again

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/> @Ashishsingh

Comment: @HB I already tried that but no luck

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio Press Build>>Rebuild Project

Answer (score 1):

Try degrading your constraint layout verison

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'
```

Use `1.1.2` or `1.1.1` instead of `2.0.0-alpha4`

Answer (score -2):

Try click on the "Sync project with Gradle files” button shown by the arrow in the Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: "Sync project with Gradle files” button in Android Studio

Comment: @Cœur Before it was posted as an Image link only so I flagged it as link only answer.